# Python - Dataframe columns out of line when appending tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have this dataframe as an example:

```
Full_name, dob, address, alt_dob
Mark Smith, 2001, Texas, alt.2002
Joe Glover, 1994, France, alt.1996 
Sarah Brown, 1982, UK, alt.1983
```

I am then using the below code to check whether the alt_dob column contains the word alt. If it does, then the entire row is appended with alt_dob data occupying the dob column for the new row.

My current code:

```
df2 = df.copy()
for tu in df.itertuples(index=False):
        if 'alt.' in tu.alt_dob:                               
            df2 = df2.append([[tu.full_name, tu.alt_dob, tu.address, tu.alt_dob]], ignore_index=True)
```

The result dataframe should look like this:

```
Full_name, dob, address, alt_dob
Mark Smith, 2001, Texas, alt.2002
Joe Glover, 1994, France, alt.1996 
Sarah Brown, 1982, UK, alt.1983
Mark Smith, alt.2002, Texas, alt.2002
Joe Glover, alt.1996, France, alt.1996 
Sarah Brown, alt.1983, UK, alt.1983
```

However, when running this code, the dataframe is instead outputted like this:

```
0,1,2,3,address,alt_dob,dob,full_name
, , , ,Texas, alt.2002, 2001, Mark Smith 
, , , ,France, alt.1996, 1994, Joe Glover
, , , ,UK, alt.1983, 1982, Sarah Brown
Mark Smith, alt.2002, Texas, alt.2002, , , ,
Joe Glover, alt.1996, France, alt.1996, , , , 
Sarah Brown, alt.1983, UK, alt.1983, , , ,
```

The appended rows are placed in new columns instead of being placed underneath the previous rows.

How can I get the appended data to fit the previous columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I got your intention right, you can use pandas' apply method -

```
def my_func(record):
     if record["alt_dob"].startswith("alt"):
         record["dob"] =r ecord["alt_dob"]
     return record

df2  = df.apply(my_func,  axis=1)
pd.concat([df, df2])
```

Comment: Similar problem, a new column '0' is created and the appended data is added to this column as one long string.

Comment: Are you sure? this is the output I got - 
`     Full_name       dob   alt_dob
0   Mark Smith      2001  alt.2002
1   Joe Glover      1994  alt.1996
2  Sarah Brown      1982  alt.1983
0   Mark Smith  alt.2002  alt.2002
1   Joe Glover  alt.1996  alt.1996
2  Sarah Brown  alt.1983  alt.1983`

Comment: Fixed by first setting df2 as a copy of df, then doing df2 = df2.apply(my_func, axis=1). Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Even if you don't define df2 in advance it should work. Anyhow, please accept the answer.